# ATOM Editor and automatic FTP upload of changed files after git merge?

Tags: git, ftp, synchronization, branch, atom-editor

I just switched from Mac CODA2 to Windows ATOM and struggle with one process which was very easy for me before. I love the ATOM in general but cant solve my current issue somehow conveniently.

I have a local directory with a PHP project. I basically change the gitmaster files and then merge those changes over about 10 different client branches. In Coda2 this was very easy because I just had projects for each client with different FTP accounts but the same local directory. When I switched a branch and merged my changes code automatically showed me the changed files and upload them to the client FTP server.

I try to do the same with ATOM but cant find a solid solution. I tested the package remote-sync-pro which does the job to upload on save and I can also watch some files or folders but it isnt a good solution for a big project with many subfolders. I could not find a way to watch the entire project at least.

Also tested remote-ftp which works fine if you want to work direct on the FTP server and online files but I was not be able to get the WATCH function work at all and my files get not uploaded then I merge.

I guess my question is how can I get it done that I can simply switch a branch, merge my changes and then automatically get ATOM to UPLOAD ALL CHANGED files to the FTP server of the client.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the perfect solution with ([Link to GIT-FTP](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp))!

Just a quick install and then I made my own little ftp_sync.bat file which contain all fit-ftp options incl. the ftp server details and placed inside the root directory of my project. Now I can always work on my project and when I switch the Branch I get always the .BAT with the FTP information from the current Branch.

After merging or editing any changes in this Branch I just call once my ftp-sync.bat and git-ftp upload/delete only files which have been changed since the last commit.

This is for me the perfect solution since it is fast and always correct. It does NOT upload anything unless you committed first which is 100% what I want.

I attach here my ftp_sync.bat for anybody who would like to use this solution as well. All existing ATOM packages did not work for me solid like this. There are good packages to upload on save via FTP but to sync latest changes did not work for me with any package.

Here my .bat for anybody who would like to use.

---

### FTP_SYNC.BAT

```
# Setup
git config git-ftp.url "ftp.domain.com/directory"
git config git-ftp.user "ftpuser"
git config git-ftp.password "ftppassword"

@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO SYSTEM: Name of your Project
ECHO TARGET: ftp.domain.com/directory
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.Push Changes (After merge - only changed files)
ECHO 2.Init Project (first time upload of all files)
ECHO 3.Catchup Project (Files are already there, only set the marker for current GIT)
ECHO 4.Download the log and show
ECHO 5.Download the log and open log
ECHO 6.Dry Run PUSH (For testing)
ECHO 7.Exit

CHOICE /C 1234567 /M "What do you want to do:"

:: Note - list ERRORLEVELS in decreasing order
IF ERRORLEVEL 7 GOTO exit
IF ERRORLEVEL 6 GOTO dryrun
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO downloadlog
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO downloadshow
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO catchupdata
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO initdata
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO pushdata

:pushdata
git ftp push -v
GOTO End

:initdata
git ftp init -v
GOTO End

:catchupdata
git ftp catchup -v
GOTO End

:downloadshow
git ftp show -v
GOTO End

:downloadlog
git ftp log -v
GOTO End

:dryrun
git ftp push -d -v
GOTO End

:exit
GOTO End

:End
```

I hope this helps also somebody else.